# Is there a react redux dispatch schedule?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I need to know, when i call something like:

```
dispatch(firstStuff());
dispatch(secondStuff());
```

if there is something like a schedule in react-redux, that gives me the guaranty, that these 2 lines will be dispatched in the right sequence.
Or is it possible that if my app has a small frame brake-in for example, it will be dispatched in a different order?

Thank you for any answere

Comment: They will **never** be dispatched in a different order.

Comment: They're not async thunks, by any chance, are they? If they are, you can `await` them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, since these dispatches are not being scheduled in any way, but executed immediately.
So if dispatching a normal action, the reducers will execute immediately before the next line (and thus, dispatch) is executed.

If those are thunks, they will be started immediately, but if you go any type of async, of course from there it can go all directions.

Comment: i tried out with following example:
console.log(x);
dispatch( changeVarX() );
console.log(x); 
the reult was the same in both console.logs, so i was wandering

Comment: Because `x` is still the same variable. If you somehow got that out from the store, it is a pointer to the old store content - and that will not change. If you are in React, you will get the new store contents on next render. You can always call `store.getState()` to get the current value from the store though.